# Angle in rotated triangle?

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $∠A=71°$ and $∠B=62°$. Triangle $ABC$ is rotated around $A$ by $114°$ to triangle $AB′C′$. Find the acute angle between $BB′$ and $AC$, in degrees.

I am unable to add the image(I don't know why). So let me explain the figure. Point $B$ is at the top, $A$ is to the right and $C$ to the left. The figure is rotated counterclockwise. It is clear that both $B'$ and $C'$ lie outside the triangle $ABC$ (since it is rotated by $114°$). This much should be sufficient. Do I need some construction to solve this problem. Without it, I am rolling in circles by angle chasing.

Comment: Hints. (1) AB = AB'? (2) $\angle C'AB' = ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Figure]

You know $\angle BAB'=114°$ since it's the angle of rotation. You also know that $\triangle BAB'$ is isosceles. So $\angle B'BA=\angle AB'B=(180°-114°)/2=33°$. Combined with $\angle BAD=\angle BAC=71°$ you know two angles in $\triangle ABD$ so you know the third:

$$\angle ADB=180°-\angle BAD-\angle DBA=180°-71°-33°=76°$$

where $\angle DBA=\angle B'BA=33°$.